# CoordinatorLayout with NestedScrollView doesn't resize with adjustResize

Tags: android, coordinator-layout, nestedscrollview

I have a `view` which contains a `CoordinatorLayout` which wraps an `AppBarLayout` and a `NestedScrollView`. Inside the `NestedScrollView` there is an `EditText`

I'm having problems showing the soft input keyboard and having it correctly resize the `view`.

With the usual flag `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` everything seems to work fine, apart from when you hide the input.

With the input open (image 2), the `NestedScrollView` (with the boring grey background) has shrunk so you can scroll to the previously "covered" portion. All good. However, once the input is hidden (image 3), the `NestedScrollView` has not grown to refill the space and you can see it's parent `CoordinatorLayout` (which I've coloured in the fetching red).

[image] [image] [image]

I've tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31286789/726954, adding a myserious `android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"` tag, but all this does is limit the `NestedScrollView` height which ends up cutting off child elements (although it does fix the problem with it refusing to refill it's container).

Am I missing something or is this a bug with the `CoordinatorLayout`

Here is a mockup of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/red_granate">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionBarContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/statusBarPadding"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/primary_material_dark"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/primary_material_dark"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2000dp">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="1900dp"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the latest version - 22.2.1? I had similar problems with 22.2.0.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
```

Comment: Take it that 22.2.0 was broken?

Comment: 22.2.0 had many problems and in a bit complicated cases it showed it. For example in RecyclerView scrollBy, there is a NPE that sometimes happens  and there are problems with row animation, that are still in 22.2.1