# adjustResize does not work with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, window-soft-input-mode

I have the following layout in my android app but I have a problem with `windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the activity:
The LinearLayout named "container" contains multiple `EditTexts` but when one of them has focus and the keyboard appears, the `Activity` does not resize and the `EditText` is hidden behind the keyboard.
I think this has something to do with the `CoordinatorLayout` but I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#F0f0f0">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/titleEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:maxLength="60"
                        android:hint="Title"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/descriptionEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:maxLength="120"
                        android:hint="Description"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I already tried [Coordinatorlayout adjustresize not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690553/coordinatorlayout-adjustresize-not-working) and I use support library 23.1.1 (not like [CoordinatorLayout with NestedScrollView doesn't resize with adjustResize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074090/coordinatorlayout-with-nestedscrollview-doesnt-resize-with-adjustresize))

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Im not able to find any solution. :( I only found that if I comment out the CollapsingToolbarLayout, then it works fine. But I need CollapsingToolbarLayout too. :( Someone please help!

Answer (score 10):

This is from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30019136/2809803).
Worked perfectly for me.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

public class KeyboardUtil {
    private View decorView;
    private View contentView;

    public KeyboardUtil(Activity act, View contentView) {
        this.decorView = act.getWindow().getDecorView();
        this.contentView = contentView;

        //only required on newer android versions. it was working on API level 19
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener);
        }
    }

    public void enable() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener);
        }
    }

    public void disable() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            decorView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener);
        }
    }


    //a small helper to allow showing the editText focus
    ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener onGlobalLayoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            //r will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.
            decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

            //get screen height and calculate the difference with the useable area from the r
            int height = decorView.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
            int diff = height - r.bottom;

            //if it could be a keyboard add the padding to the view
            if (diff != 0) {
                // if the use-able screen height differs from the total screen height we assume that it shows a keyboard now
                //check if the padding is 0 (if yes set the padding for the keyboard)
                if (contentView.getPaddingBottom() != diff) {
                    //set the padding of the contentView for the keyboard
                    contentView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, diff);
                }
            } else {
                //check if the padding is != 0 (if yes reset the padding)
                if (contentView.getPaddingBottom() != 0) {
                    //reset the padding of the contentView
                    contentView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    };


    /**
     * Helper to hide the keyboard
     *
     * @param act
     */
    public static void hideKeyboard(Activity act) {
        if (act != null && act.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) act.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(act.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use it in your activity by doing the following:

//initialize the KeyboardUtil (you can do this global)

```
KeyboardUtil keyboardUtil = new KeyboardUtil(this, findViewById(android.R.id.content));

//enable it
keyboardUtil.enable();
```

To disable this resizing, do this

```
//disable it
keyboardUtil.disable();
```

Comment: I've tried this and it does not work for me. I've only enabled this once in onCreate(). Is there anything else I should do?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Comment: what if I want the fitSystemWindow feature why should I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="#F0f0f0">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>



    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/titleEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLength="60"
                android:hint="Title"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/descriptionEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLength="120"
                android:hint="Description"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</NestedScrollView>
```

Use this xml, Hope it will work

Comment: Thanks but even after moving the `LinearLayout` the `Activity` doesn't resize :/

Comment: try to use   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysVisible|stateVisible" instead of adjustRize

Comment: Had similar problem. 
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" was the key
Thanks

Comment: It worked for me to remove android:fitsSystemWindows="true". Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 0):

just wrap your `CoordinatorLayout` with `RelativeLayout` and put `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your `RelativeLayout`